# Simple way to encrypt and decrypt a backup file in bash

Tags: bash, encryption

I need to encrypt a backup file gzip.
I performed the following operation.,

```
    tar -Pzcvf  $dir/*.xml >/dev/null | gpg --yes --batch --passphrase PaSsW0rD -o "$bpath/$bfile".tar.gz
```

But it is failing with the following error.,

```
     gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
```

I just need a simple passsord protected backup file. Any other alternative solutions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Doing it your way :

```
tar -zcvf your_tar_file_name.tar.gz "$dir"/*.xml && gpg --symmetric  --cipher-algo AES256 your_tar_file_name.tar.gz
```

Note that I do not wish to preserve absolute names, so I have stripped the **P** option from tar. The default output file in this case is `your_tar_file_name.tar.gz.gpg`.

To decrypt and get the files back you may do :

```
gpg -o my_tar_file.tar.gz -d your_tar_file_name.tar.gz.gpg && tar -xzf my_tar_file.tar.gz
```

This uses a symmetric encryption scheme, ie, we could use the same password to decrypt the file.  The above command will ask you to enter the password for encryption and confirm it.

If you wish to do asymmetric encryption using gpg have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/gpg-encryption-guide-part-2-asymmetric.html).

**Option 2**

You may also use **aescrypt**

Download aescrypt from [here](https://www.aescrypt.com/download/)

Once installed you may use the straight-forward GUI to encrypt the file.

If  you need the command line tool, you could use the aescrypt command like below:

```
 tar zcvf your_tar_file_name.tar.gz "$dir"/*.xml && aescrypt -e -p yourstrongpassword your_tar_file_name.tar.gz
```

Here **e** is for encryption and **p** is for password. The output will usually be stored in `your_tar_file_name.tar.gz.aes`.

You could decrypt the `your_tar_file_name.tar.gz.aes` file using

```
aescrypt -d -p yourstrongpassword your_tar_file_name.tar.gz.aes
```

Here **d** is for decryption.

Comment: The [correct link for **symmetric** encryption is this](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/gpg-encryption-guide-part-4-symmetric.html).